# Issues storing JSON data in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, json, sessionstorage

I'm trying to utilize HTML5 sessionStorage to retain some data previously retrieved from an external API, so as to cache the data when it is later called again, rather than making a connection to retrieve redundant data that has already been retrieved this session.

```
function getItemWithTooltip(item_id, div_id) {
var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url2 = "https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/"+item_id;

xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function() {if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {parseItemTooltip(xmlhttp2.responseText);}};
xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
//xmlhttp2.send();

var item;

var cache_enabled = true;
// Cache results for quicker page loads
if (cache_enabled == true){
    if (Storage !== void(0)) {
        // Retrieve data (if stored)
        if (sessionStorage[String(item_id)]) {
            //item = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(String(item_id)));
            item = JSON.parse(sessionStorage[item_id.toString()]);
            //window.alert("sessionStorage: Retrieved");
            //alert(typeof (item));
            //alert(item);
        }
    }
}

if (item == null){
    xmlhttp2.send();
}

  function parseItemTooltip(response) {
    //var item = JSON.parse(response);

    if (item == null){
        // Store data
        if (cache_enabled == true){sessionStorage.setItem(item_id.toString(), JSON.stringify(response));}
        //sessionStorage.setItem(String(item_id), item);
        //if (cache_enabled == true){sessionStorage.setItem(String(item_id), response);}
        //window.alert("sessionStorage: Stored");
        item = JSON.parse(response);
    }
    //..More code here that was not relevant and removed to save space..
  }
}
```

Comment: PS:  It works the first time through, when it retrieves the data remotely, however it fails to work using data retrieved from sessionStorage. :(

Comment: have you a sample of your json to show?

Comment: Have you made sure that `sessionStorage[String(item_id)]` actually works?

Comment: Yes, that part is working.

Comment: Either String(item_id)   or also  item_id.toString()   both seem to work ok.

Comment: Uncommenting //alert(item); seems to also show me the correct JSON data was indeed saved, however it's not letting me parse it as I do the real data retrieved remotely,  I would expect the data to be the same, and appears to be the same to my eye, however something is different about it, as it does not parse the same.

Comment: Eineki: here is a sample of JSON data:

Comment: {
  "name": "Superior Rune of Holding",
  "description": "Used to craft 20 slot bags, boxes, and packs.",
  "type": "CraftingMaterial",
  "level": 0,
  "rarity": "Exotic",
  "vendor_value": 12500,
  "game_types": [
    "Activity",
    "Wvw",
    "Dungeon",
    "Pve"
  ],
  "flags": [],
  "restrictions": [],
  "id": 13009,
  "chat_link": "[&AgHRMgAA]",
  "icon": "https://render.guildwars2.com/file/CFA856D1EE9F01056490EE1CD2C637C2C1C5CBA6/63501.png"
}

Comment: Will it help to see a page live?

Comment: http://rab.rickbrodeur.com/gw2_recipe_search.html?item=13009

Comment: See that it loads the first time, but then press refresh, and it should now load from cache the same data, but fails in parsing the data.

Comment: Also worth noting, I made the var cache_enabled = true; so I could enable or disable the beta-caching feature, and when I disable it all my other code works as expected.

Comment: I have also tried variations of using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, as well as without them, since the data is already JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has something to do with the fact that you `JSON.stringify` the response when storing it. The response is already a string, so that's going to "double-stringify" it and when you parse it you will only get the original string back.

You do both `JSON.stringify` AND `JSON.parse` on the response text. This makes no sense for JSON, you should only need to do one of these. If you stringify a string, it will become "double-stringified". If you try to parse an object, you will get error because `JSON.parse` requires a string.

Lets say your response text looks like this:

`'{"property":"value"}'`

It's a string. Now, when you stringify it, it will become this:

`'"{\"property\":\"value\"}"'`

When you parse this, like you do when getting it from `sessionStorage`, you will only get the original string back. You would have to parse it again to get the object you want.

When you do that parse on the response text directly, you correctly get the object:

```
{
  property: "value"
}
```

So what you need to do is to store the response text in `sessionStorage` without stringifying it.

---

You're also only invoking `parseItemTooltip` in the state change handler for the request, so it never gets invoked when you get the cached item. Looking at your full code, I can see that you do basically everything in this function so you need to invoke it explicitly when not performing the request.

Comment: I have also tried variations of using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, as well as without them, since the data is already JSON.

Comment: Changing this: if (cache_enabled == true){sessionStorage.setItem(item_id.toString(), JSON.stringify(response));}
To this: if (cache_enabled == true){sessionStorage.setItem(item_id.toString(), response);}

Comment: I am retrieving it with:  item = JSON.parse(sessionStorage[item_id.toString()]);

Comment: Also looked at your actual code, you do a lot of stuff with the object in your `parseItemTooltip` function but that function only runs when you do the actual AJAX request, when you get it from `sessionStorage` you don't do anything with `item`

Comment: I do appreciated you answering though, and for trying to help me. :D

Comment: It should do the same thing with item, whether it is gotten remotely or by sessionStorage,  do you see something in my code that is preventing that?

Comment: Remember to clear your session storage after making that code change as you otherwise still have those items cached in the wrong format.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake, That function is only called if the httprequest is sent, which in this case it is not sent.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you were specifically trying to point out to me, but either way your insight helped me to discover the flaw.  Thank you! I will post an update if I get it fixed, and let you all know. :D

Comment: Exactly, and the way you have structured it, all you have to do is to add an `else` block to your `if (item == null)` where you explicitly invoke `parseItemTooltip()`. BTW `item == null` can be simplified as `!item`.

Comment: I would also suggest that you don't open the `XMLHttpRequest` unless you're actually going to send it, i.e. put `xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true)` in the same `if` block as `xmlhttp2.send()`

Comment: if (item == null){
  xmlhttp2.send();
 }
 else {
  parseItemfromStorage(item);
 }

Comment: if (item == null){
  xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
  xmlhttp2.send();
 }
 else {
  parseItemfromStorage(item);
 }

Comment: if (!item){
  xmlhttp2.open("GET", url2, true);
  xmlhttp2.send();
 }
 else {
  parseItemfromStorage(item);
 }

Comment: I think I have made all the suggestions you mentioned.

Comment: I must have some other issue still. It's still not working.  I think I have made some progress though.

Comment: Storing and retrieving from `sessionStorage` seems to work properly now anyway, so you'll have to look into further issues from here. I did notice that it errors when trying to set `innerHTML` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well after bugging-out at my code for another hour, I finally figured out the issue, and it was something stupid simple, like it usually is.

My answer was to reverse these two lines:

```
    getItemWithTooltip(item.id, div_ID);
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
```

To this:

```
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    getItemWithTooltip(item.id, div_ID);
```

Reasoning: It was trying to fill in the div before it was being created. 
Previously it didn't matter, because it was filled in while waiting for the remote server response, 
however now with data cached into sessionStorage, it was retrieved so fast, that the order did become a factor. 
Always good to pay attention to logical order of progression.

Thank you to everyone who contributed to debugging this. Much thanks, and appreciation! 
Quick responses, and friendly people.  Made for a great time for a first-timer on this website.